# Adding CircularProgressIndicator in infinite scroll Flutter

Tags: flutter, infinite-scroll

I did infinite scroll but i want  to add CircularProgressIndicator while it is loading list items, I could not do it. so how can i add CircularProgressIndicator based on the code down:

```
  ListView.builder( 
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
    vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    primary: false,
    itemCount: _con.brandComplaints.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
     if (_con.isLoadingComplaints == false) {
            return Padding(
                 padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                 bottom: 15.0),
                 child: ComplaintItemWidget(
                 complaint: _con.brandComplaints
                .elementAt(index),
                  ),
               );
    } else {
           return Center(
             child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                     }
                   },
               ),
```

----------------------------Scroll Listener for scrolling list items ----------------------------------

```
  _scrollListener() {
    if (int.parse(_con.brand.complaintTotal) == _con.brandComplaints.length) {
      return;
    }
    //print(_scrollController.position.extentAfter);
    if (_scrollController.position.extentAfter <= 0 && isPageLoading ==false) {

      _con.listenForBrandComplaints(_con.brand.id);
    }
  }
```

---------------------------Controller -------------------------------

```
  void listenForBrandComplaints(String idBrand) async {
    //setState(() => isLoadingComplaints = true);
    final Stream<Complaint> stream =
        await getBrandComplaints(idBrand, brandComplaints.length);
    stream.listen((Complaint _complaint) {
      setState(() => brandComplaints.add(_complaint));
    }, onError: (a) {
      //setState(() => isLoadingComplaints = false);
      print(a);
    }, onDone: () {
      //setState(() => isLoadingComplaints = false);
      //complaintOffset += brandComplaints.length;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using the `Stack` widget and overlapping the `CircularProgressIndicator` with the `ListView`. Check the code below for a simplified example:

```
class LoadingOnScroll60619794 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingOnScroll60619794State createState() => _LoadingOnScroll60619794State();
}

class _LoadingOnScroll60619794State extends State<LoadingOnScroll60619794> {
  bool _loading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
            onPressed: runLoading
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text('item 1'),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text('item 1'),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text('item 1'),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text('item 1'),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text('item 1'),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text('item 1'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          _loading
            ? Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
            : SizedBox(width: 0, height: 0,)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void runLoading(){
    setState(() {
      _loading = true;
    });
    Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 1500), (){
      setState(() {
        _loading = false;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: But its only working when you press on button, I want when i swap up the loading progress indicator will come until data is fetching

Comment: The button press is just an example. You just need to use setState and set _loading variable to true, while the data is being fetched, and then do the same and pass it to false once the data is received.

Comment: If the answer worked for you, please mark it as correct. Also consider upvoting for relevance.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by either returning a regular list item or a `CircularProgressIndicator` in `itemBuilder`, while `isPageLoading` is `true`. Also `itemCount` should be increased by 1, in order to show all the list items and a progress item.

And instead of complicated `ScrollController` conditions, you can just use `NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>` with `ScrollEndNotification` event.

It works like this:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
    onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
      if (scrollNotification is ScrollEndNotification) {
        onScrollListener();
      }

      return true;
    },
    child: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverAppBar(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
          title: const Text('Infinite scrolling SliverList'),
        ),
        SliverList.separated(
          separatorBuilder: (_, __) => Divider(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            // Show progress indicator on the bottom
            if (allFlowers.value.length == index) {
              return const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, bottom: 16),
                child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
              );
            }

            final flowerName = allFlowers.value[index];

            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 16),
              child: Text(
                flowerName,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          itemCount: isPageLoading.value ? allFlowers.value.length + 1 : allFlowers.value.length,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);

void onScrollListener() {
  if (reachedEnd.value) {
    return;
  }

  if (!isPageLoading.value) {
    isPageLoading.value = true;
    Future.microtask(() async {
      final newFlowers = await getFlowersUseCase.getFlowers(page: nextPage.value);
      if (newFlowers.length < pageSize) {
        reachedEnd.value = true;
      } else {
        nextPage.value++;
      }

      allFlowers.value.addAll(newFlowers);
      isPageLoading.value = false;
    });
  }
}
```

I've added a complete [code example here](https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/infinite-scrolling-sliverlist-in-flutter-2236aa050a6c).